# Exporting to eps loses font/symbol information?

Tags: plotting, eps-format

I have already asked [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67327/exporting-to-eps-loses-font-information) question, which has helped. However, now my parenthesis are coming out as Courier "H" and "L." How do I work around this? Is there an easier way to save a plot as EPS without having to change the characters line-by-line?

Comment: The issue is it wants to render the parenthesis using mathematica fonts. I don't see a work around.  Can you see if you have the same issue with "pdf" (That *should* properly embed the font..).

Comment: I prefer eps since I'm putting these figures in a LaTeX document. With pdf figures, the file size is way too big.

Comment: interesting, on inspection on both my systems (windows and linux ) the mathematica fonts *are* embedded in the eps. Can you open an example in a text editor and look for `/FontName /Mathematica1 def` ? If its there maybe your problem is with your viewer..

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18977/8), and that the answer is to include `BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" ->False}}`.

However, be aware of [some issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25572/8), and (on v10) [this change of syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63001/8).

If this solves your issue, I will link the questions by marking yours as a duplicate.